# Need help identifying and fixing older shower control

Tags: shower, plumbing-fixture

[image][image]So the shower control fell off - there is no identifying brand name or model number that I can see.  The house was built in 2004 and the other shower/bath faucets are Hansgrohe/Grohe, but looking through their website/internet search hasn't yielded a match.  There is a screw that seems like I could just tighten at the front of the knob, but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Anyone familiar this faucet that can advise?  Thank you.

Comment: A picture of it might be helpful.

Comment: _Hey, I don't know what kind of car I've got. It's got 4 tires and there's a key slot in the door but it doesn't seem to do anything and I can't find a badge on it. There are a lot of Fords in my neighborhood, so I looked through the Ford website but didn't see anything similar. What kind of car do I have?_ Honestly, that's all you gave us to go on. Please, help us help you!

Comment: Sorry - thought I had included pictures, but I guess I missed a step.  Pictures added.

Answer (score 0):

You might know this already, but Hansgrohe and Grohe are two totally different companies. Make sure you check both websites, and even better, check the websites of supply companies (just google "Grohe valves price"). They often have better pictures, while the manufacturers sometimes don't list parts of 'legacy' products. I found spare parts for my 25 year old, no longer made shower this way.

Comment: I did not know they were different.  Will check what I can find searching for old Hansgrohe stuff.  Thank you.

Comment: Try these: https://www.ferguson.com and https://www.chicagofaucetshoppe.com/